# Is heat transfer in space through radiation 100% efficient?

Tags: thermodynamics, space

Flat 1x1 meter plate.  Heat source indicated by red arrow.  The rest is in space.  No sun exposure at all.

[image: Parallel plates]

Some of the photons will exit through the gaps between plates.  No problem.  My question is about the photons that do make it from plate to plate.

One photon leaves the first plate and is received by the second.  Is this transfer of heat 100% efficient?  If not, why?  If the energy does not go into heat, where does it go?

A variant of this question would be a hypothetical sphere heat source inside a much larger hollow sphere in space.  Is heat transfer through radiation from the small sphere in the center to the larger outer sphere 100% efficient?

Let's define the term:  "100% efficient" is taken to mean that one unit of energy carried away by a photon from the source delivers one unit of energy to the destination.

Does the angle of incidence matter?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the transfer is 100% efficient. we can use $E=h \nu$ to calculate the energy of the photon with frequency $\nu$. This is the amount the emitting plate looses and the absorbing plate gains. This is not dependent on the angle of incident, as long as the photon is completely absorbed.

The conservation of energy is a general concept. We use it all the time in physics.

Comment: Right.  I was just trying to see if there were secondary effects I did not know about that would carry away some of the energy.  In other words, one photon goes in, some of the energy is turned into heat right at the fin and some of it exits as a subatomic particle or something like that.  Still conservation of energy, of course, but there would be a component that causes less than 100% of it to be transferred from fin to fin.  So far I have not found anything that indicates anything less than 100% is transferred BTW.

Comment: One would need huge photon energies just to create the particles. E.g. an electron has a rest mass of 511keV. Hence, the creation of an electron positron pair (our just a quantum fluctuation) is impossible, if one considers photons in the visible spectrum (or less energetic).